# How to get route Params of parent view?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am wondering if it is possible to get route parameters of a parent view, from its child view?

Thanks!

Comment: just send it via `<a [routerLink]="['../abc', {'key': value}">` i think does't matter from parent view or child one ?

Comment: @PardeepJain, that adds additional param to your child view. Seems very unintuitive that this should actually work as intended.

Comment: could you please post more code what you'r trying to do ?

Comment: Please check now....

Answer (score 0):

- **[Plunker - How to get route Params of parent view for nested views](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPDpUtTpklymlFf7iQhv?p=preview)**

> Boot.ts
>  |___Home (cone)
>  |___Product (ctwo) 
>           |_____productOne 
>           |_____producttwo

**boot.ts** has  **Home tab** & **Product tab**.
 **Product(ctwo) cmp** has `routeconfig` from where we can go to **productOne cmp** & **productTwo cmp** .

***What I want***

Now, when I click to **product tab(from boot.ts view)**, I want to redirect to **product(ctwo) & its view** and want to load **productOne cmp & its view**  ***`with RouteParam`*** from `product tab`.
**Note**: *to do this I don't use `useAsDefault`*

***boot.ts***

```
<div >
      <div><a [routerLink]="['ComponentOne']">Home</a><hr/></div>
      <div><a [routerLink]="['./ComponentTwo',{id: 1234}, 'ProductOne']">Product </a></div>
</div>

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/ComponentOne', name: 'ComponentOne', component: ComponentOne, useAsDefault:true},
  {path:'/ComponentTwo/...', name: 'ComponentTwo', component: ComponentTwo}
])
```

***product(Ctwo).ts***

```
constructor(params: RouteParams){
              console.log("Second component being called");
               this.id = params.get('id');
}
```

***productOne.ts***

```
constructor(rp:RouteParams,rd:RouteData,injector: Injector){

      let params = injector.parent.parent.get(RouteParams); 
      this.id = params.get('id');
}
```

*Sorry for naming conventions*